# [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todo]" not connected to #todo in another div

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-drag-drop

`[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todo]"` not connected to #todo in another div using Angular 9

it says the property "todo" does not exist on "Component_name"

```
cdkDropList #todo="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="unScheduleTasksArray"           [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[prog]" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
```

another div is

```
cdkDropList #prog="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="scheduleTasksArray"
[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todo]" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
```

Comment: Please include the code you were using that cause this. We can't do much with just this info. I would also suggest reading [tour] and [ask] if you haven't already.

Comment: Sorry but could you put it in the question?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Why are you using #todo? If you are trying to set a custom property instead of a default existing one then just first try removing the # and seeing if that works. Also when I asked for the code I meant the full code. For example if it is a div then show <div> and </div> as appropriate.